# Washer stops half way through wash cycle

Tags: washing-machine

Our Whirlpool Ultimate Care II stopped working in the middle of the wash cycle tonight.  No noise, just stopped.  Restarted it and it did it again, and again, and again.  Any ideas on what might be going on?  We would like to figure it out ourselves if possible.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: the only way to start to figure it out, is to determine the exact spot in the cycle where it stopped .... "middle of the wash cycle"  is an unclear description

Comment: I think it's right after agitating.  When it's supposed to soak and start draining before the rinse cycle.

Comment: i have a whirlpool gold dryer that would randomly kill itself by tripping the breaker, while in the middle of a cycle. i replaced the heater element; no change. turns out the problem was the circuit breaker itself... thing had reached the end of its reliable life.

Answer (score 0):

"Middle of the wash cycle". Literally in the middle of agitating? Or is it actually at **what should be the start of spin/drain**?

If it is at start of spin/drain then the problem is very likely the lid switch. This is the switch that stops the spin cycle immediately if you lift the lid. The switches wear out - I replace mine every few years. Actually, I have a Kenmore, but the Kenmore top-loaders and Whirlpool have been one-and-the-same for many years. You should look up (Google is your friend) the lid switch part number based on your exact washer model number, but they are all pretty similar. Plenty of YouTube videos on how to replace the switch.

It is possible to bypass the lid switch, and I have seen that done (I have only done that myself for testing purposes) but I **do NOT recommend doing that** because if you ever have a situation where a full load starts draining and your house main drain is backing up you want to be able to stop the washer IMMEDIATELY by just lifting the lid.

Comment: I think it's the beginning of the soak/drain cycle before the rinse starts.  Would that still be the lid switch?

Comment: End of the soak ready to drain - Yes that would be lid switch.

Comment: The design seems to have changed over time.  My previous Kenmore/Whirlpool washer would run the agitator with the lid up, but wouldn't spin unless the lid was closed.  I have a newer version of that washer now, and it won't agitate or spin with the lid up.

Comment: Most definitely, my new design lg top load washer has 2 reed switches to detect the door, has a locking mechanism on the lid, so I bypassed the first reed switch, changed the locking mechanism to a manual over ride switch and left one switch on the control panel towards the front so the washer stops when the lid opens still, crazy technology

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/wN7WlWGVrR8

Take a look at this YouTube video on your problem / issue.

I believe the answer could indeed be the lid switch.

Comment: I was just about to say that right before I scrolled down haha, it needs to detect that the door is shut before it starts spinning 100 mph, safety first. Cant have a child or forgetful parent opening the door if its spinning like that... I got rid of my switch and put a manual on off switch on the back of the washer, these little lid switches are too cheap